# Arduino parsing a uint8_t variable using strtok()

Tags: parsing, arduino, strtok

I have a uint8_t variable for example '01:2.7:300:4'. It comes in on an Arduino acting as a transceiver.

I want to parse the variable by the colon (:) using strtok(). However, the first argument of strtok is required to be a char*.

Is there a way to convert the uint8_t variable to a char? or is there another way to parse the input?

I searched google for the last few hours but have been unable to find a solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's a bit ugly, you can simply cast the `uint8_t*` to a `char*` and `strtok` will work fine (at least, on all normal platforms, including Arduino):